# How to Create Custom Grid Filter Show All "NULL" Values in Specific Column

Tags: magento2, module, grid, custom, filter

How can I make a filter for null values of my order ID

```
<column name="order_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>                    
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

[image]

If a enter NULL in my filtering it should just show all row where Order ID is NULL or Blank

[image]

Comment: Did you make this work ?

Answer (score -1):

This can be done easily, first make you sure if there are no values then column has null value instead of empty. Then when use filter it will wo

Comment: dafuq? Is something missing on the comment?